# text floating around image in special way

Tags: image, css, css-float

I'm trying to make a special floating text around an image. It has to look like this
[Open image here](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/189/imagefloat.gif/)

Text can vary in size. Image has a fixed size.

How do we set this up in CSS? Is it even possible?

I'll take a scripted solution if there is one (all though I can't see anything helpfull in that department myself...)

Thanks a lot in advance :-)

Jan

Comment: how much are you paying per hr? :P

Comment: Yes - I tried several things. Main problem is to have the first 2-3 lines of text fill the entire container and the rest of the text being nicely floated next to the image. Combining those two methods seems like a problem.........or at least for me it is :-)

Comment: Show that you've put in some effort, and give us that example code. People aren't going to be willing to help out if you want the solution just handed to you.

Comment: All right. Sorry. I'll keep that in mind next time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to `float: right` your image:

```
​img { float:right;  }​
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/KuD93/2/)

Comment: Thanks. This was (partly) what I was looking for. I'll use PHP to split up the text in two. Show first part then the image (floated to the right) and finally the rest of the text. Works perfect

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fiddle showing how to do it: http://jsfiddle.net/4q3um/

```
img {
 float:right;
 margin:0 0 20px 20px;
 width:100px;
}
```